# xslfo with FOP: Check if content overflows and call different template?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a question with XSLFO, generator is FOP. What I wanna do:
In the PDF I wanna generate an item list, each item is in a box with a specific width and height. In case the content does not fit this box, the content should be displayed in a bigger box (with also specific dimensions).

I do not see any way to reach that in XSLFO, especially with FOP.

Has someone an idea to solve that?

Thanks for every idea!!

Comment: you could only make a rough guess based on the amount of text you had wether there would be too much for the small box, there is no way of measuring it

Comment: Yes, I see. But unfortunately I have to support many different languages, so I can not even guess :-/. But thank you!! :)

Comment: Counting how many characters you have in the whole box will give you a pretty good idea

Comment: No, it does not. Characters don't have the same width. And what makes it more difficult: The characters have a different width and the languages have, even if they use e.g. latin chars, totally different characters of primary use. So one sentence can fit in one language just half of a row, in another language it can use two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate, independent processing steps involved here:

1. Generation of XSL-FO markup (using a stylesheet and an XSLT processor).
2. Rendering of XSL-FO markup as PDF (using a FO processor, such as FOP).

The second step cannot influence the first. It is not possible to test for overflow conditions during rendering and somehow decide what template to invoke. There is no feedback loop. What you are asking for is not possible.

---

It is possible to do crude text fitting by estimating the length of text strings in XSLT. That is the idea behind ["Saxon Extension for Guessing Composed Text String Length"](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/XSL-FO/message/5499).

I have not used this extension, and it may not even be available anymore (the announcement about it is from 2004). In any case, this is very far from an actual layout feedback mechanism.

Comment: Yes, my question was not specific enough, that's true and you're right, I'm using in the first step a XSLT-processing.